# Breeze Framework - how to do an inline Subtable Count query

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, breeze

I have a table Supplier, with subtable 1 to many Product.  I would like to replicate the results of this query in Breeaze:

```
SELECT *,
(select count(*) from Product where Supplier.id  = Product.SupplierId) ProductCount
FROM Supplier
```

Basically, I'd like to have an output of the Supplier data columns, with an appended column of that supplier's product count.

I currently have this query in Breeze which gives me suppliers, but I don't see a way to add the count column to the results.  I already have a field in the Entity ProductCount in place and NonMappable to contain it:

```
var query = _repository.Suppliers.AsQueryable();
            if (supplierIds.Length > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(supplier => supplierIds.Contains(supplier.Id));
                var result = query.ToList();
            }
            return query;
```

What am I missing?  Is there a way to do this in Breeze or no?

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: You could try adding this server-side as a computed property to the entity's model, and then adding the property to the entity constructor (not initializer) client-side so the computed property is returned from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the inlineCount property in Breeze query structure :

```
successFunction([data]) {
  ....
}
```

you can get :

**results :** fields of the query (array)

**inlineCount :**
Only available if 'inlineCount(true)' was applied to the query. Returns the count of items that would have been returned by the query before applying any skip or take operators, but after any filter/where predicates would have been applied.

For instance :

```
var query = new EntityQuery("Clients")
  .where("ClientName", "startsWith", "B")
  .take(20)
  .orderBy("ClientName")
  .inlineCount(true);
```

The result

```
query.execute().then( function(data) {
data.results
data.inlineCount
}
```

The ***data.inlineCount*** column will return 12 if your query contains 12 clients name started with "B" even if the total records returned may totalized 20.

Comment: I saw that function in the documentation.  Its close but not quite what I need.

I have a Supplier object that contains multiple Products.  I need the Supplier's columns, with a column that contains the count of Products belonging to that supplier.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a ProductCount property on your Supplier entity, you just need to return it from the server.  If ProductCount is on the *server-side* entity, you can populate the property on the server and the client side will just work:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Supplier> SuppliersWithProductCount()
{
    var query = _repository.Suppliers.AsQueryable();
    // ...add server-side params to the query, if desired...

    // Get objects with the supplier and the count
    var list = query.Select(s => new { Supplier = s, Count = s.Products.Count }).ToList();
    // Set the count on the Supplier
    list.ForEach(o => o.Supplier.ProductCount = o.Count);
    // Extract the Suppliers
    var suppliers = list.Select(o => o.Supplier);
    return suppliers.AsQueryable();
}
```

On the other hand, if the ProductCount property only exists on the *client*, you will need to pass it to the client separately, and set the property on the client-side entities in your query result handler.
On the server:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Object> SuppliersWithProductCount()
{
    var query = ContextProvider.Context.Suppliers.AsQueryable();
    // ...add server-side params to the query, if desired...

    // Get objects with the supplier and the count
    return query.Select(s => new { Supplier = s, Count = s.Products.Count });
}
```

On the client:

```
  EntityQuery.from("SuppliersWithProductCount")
   .using(myEntityManager).execute()
   .then(function (data) {
       // results are { Supplier, Count } objects
       var results = data.results;
       var suppliers = [];
       results.forEach(function (r) {
           r.Supplier.ProductCount = r.Count;
           suppliers.push(r.Supplier);
       });
       return suppliers;
   });
```